# Linq Query to get two different values from a single list

Tags: c#, linq

```
Date           value
10/03/2014      77  
10/02/2015      66

10/01/2016      12    
10/01/2016      34
10/01/2016      55

---
---
```

Till 30 records

I want to write a linq Query to get Values for last 30 days plus one
 value before last 30 days.

So I want a response

All these records

```
10/01/2016      12    
10/01/2016      34
10/01/2016      55

---
---
```

Plus one record

```
10/02/2015      66
```

Just want to know is it even possible or should I get these values in
two different query. Note I am using mongodb.

Comment: Can you show the class that holds the data and the code you are using to query the data?

Comment: Could you please change the date formats to ISO standard so that we can all understand the dates? `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: It is possible. How does the class for your record look like?

Comment: Actually, adding the class definition plus compilable code for your data would also be good.

Comment: Sorry cant share that .. an idea will be helpful to group those 30 records + one record before that 30 record. Thanks

Comment: Either look for "where startdate between range or enddate between range". Or if you do not have an enddate query startdate in range + last startdate before your range.

Comment: If you cannot share from your real project, please build up a minimized example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the few information:

```
var last30Days = sourceList.Where(rec => rec.DateField.Date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30));
var firstOneAfter30Days = sourceList.Where(rec => rec.DateField.Date < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30)).Take(1);
var allTogether = last30Days.Union(firstOneAfter30Days);
```

Note: `Take(1)` could be `FirstOrDefault()` too. You might write it in one line but this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following.  I have used `source` to refer to your record set.

```
//Create your "Last 30 days" timeframe
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;    
DateTime startDate = endDate.AddDays(-30);

//Use a query to get the "one before" record
var firstBeforeStart = source.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Date < startDate);

//Use the date of the "one before" record to calculate a query start date
var queryStart = firstBeforeStart == null ? startDate : firstBeforeStart.Date;

//Run another query to get all data based on the amended query start date
var allRecords = source.Where(i => i.Date >= queryStart && i.Date < endDate);
```